# Can someone please go over my Arduino design?

Tags: arduino, design, eaglecad

I've decided to design a custom Arduino in order to learn about EAGLE and electronic design. I referenced Arduino schematics off of various sites so I think my design is good, but I'd appreciate some feedback before I go onto PCB layout.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you have to show us your design if you want us to review it

Comment: just added a link, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design looks good, however I have a fwe comments:

- It is not a good idea put voltage regulators in cascade. Connect both regulator's input to the power supply;
- The name of the regulators will be good;
- 10K is the most common value of pull-up resistors at 5V, I'd change it.
- Why CTS (FTDI_DEVICE) is connected to GND?

Comment: What about a power-on reset circuit - even a 1uF to ground? Is there much of a big deal about regulators in cascade - what's the big issue on this design? I didn't follow what you meant about 10k resistors and the CTS to ground thing? For the OP - it would be way better if you posted your circuit into the question then folk would see an understandable question with a potentially understandable answer.

Comment: I completely disagree with cascading regulators.  Not only is this very (very) common practice, it can be a much wiser choice compared to parallel to input, depending on the design.

Comment: @JamesC4S - I agree strongly that cascading the regulators is the correct thing to do in this application. One of the reasons this is laid out this way is because the USB connection injects 5V onto the 5V rail. If you weren't running the 3.3V regulator from the 5V rail, the MCU could not be powered over USB.

Comment: Furthermore, 12v into a 3.3v linear reg will dump (8.7v * amperage) of energy into heat. By cascading, you reduce that dramatically. In fact, that's how the real arduinos do it. 12v jack to 5v reg to 3.3v reg (or usb to 3.3v reg)

Answer (score 0):

Your decoupling seems to be based on "common belief" and not actual need.  You really don't need 10uF caps on the input the 328.  1u in parallel with 0.1uF will be sufficient.  There's really no need for a 10uF on the input of the 5V regulator.  Your regulator will work well there, unless the input is AC.

The 330ohm current limit resistor for LED1 is probably fine mathematically, but how bright do you need a power indicator?  1K (like what's used on the Arduino indicators) is usually enough for indicators.

While not specified in the schematic, make sure you only use a C0G (aka NP0) capacitor for the crystal's capacitors.

Comment: Would I even need the capacitors on the input to the 328? Since I have the caps at the output of the regulator the voltage should already be sufficiently smoothed, correct?